# Why does the error "Uninitialized constant DriverManager" occur in previously functioning code?

Tags: java, ruby, jdbc, driver, jruby

I'm working with jruby and I'm making calls to a DB2/BIGSQL database via the db2jcc4.jar file. I was making connections perfectly fine both inserts and selects, and then all of a sudden I started getting the error "uninitialized constant DriverManager."

The file db2jcc4.jar is readable and has the correct permissions. I even went back to a previously working, earlier version of the code and I get the same error. The only notable change is that the server was restarted.

```
require 'java'

java_import 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'
java_import 'java.util.Properties'

url = "jdbc:db2://SERVER-REMOVED:PORT_REMOVED/BIGSQL"
output, rset, stmt, conn = nil

begin
  properties = java.util.Properties.new
  properties['user'] = 'USER REMOVED'
  properties['password'] = 'PASSWORD REMOVED'

  # Load driver class
  driver = DB2Driver.new

  DriverManager.registerDriver driver #this comes out to nil
  regDrivers = DriverManager.getDrivers
  conn = DriverManager.get_connection url, properties
  ...
```

Any idea what happened?

Comment: Of course, the answer of DavidFlorenz correctly shows how to fix your problem, but to answer your question, why you get this error message: Constants in Ruby are identifiers which start  with an upper case letter. At the time you want to run `DriverManager.registerDriver`, Ruby sees the constant `DriverManager`, and obviously has not seen a definition for this constant yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to import the DriverManager class

```
java_import 'java.sql.DriverManager'
```

Comment: Thanks! It's so weird that it worked fine for like two days without this line of code and then stopped working.